# Incoming Call Block in Android Exception

Tags: java, android

I am trying to block incoming call in Android using this method but this through 
this exception.I have tried so many methods but failed to abort incoming call please help what is the problem with this code.I have also added ITelephony interface inside **com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony**.

**Exception**

[image]
**Code**

```
String Messageofenemy;
String Blckno;

public OutgoingReceiver() {
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {


        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {


            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(i);
            return;
        }


        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {

            //outgoing call code here

        } else {
            //get the phone state
            String newPhoneState = intent.hasExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE) ?
                    intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE) : null;
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (newPhoneState != null &&
                    newPhoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                //read the incoming call number
                String phoneNumber =
                        bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                Cursor res = db.getAllrows();
                if (res.getCount() == 0) {

                } else {

                    while (res.moveToNext()) {

                        Blckno = res.getString(0);

                    }


                }
                if (phoneNumber.equals("03352264769")) {

                    try {

                        AudioManager am =
                                (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                        am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                        ITelephony telephonyService;
                        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
                                context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        try {
                            Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                            m.setAccessible(true);
                            telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
                            telephonyService.endCall();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Exception" + String.valueOf(e),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Exception is " + String.valueOf(e),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }


            }


        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Error is " + String.valueOf(ex),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}


}
```

Comment: Please Format your code

Comment: I have formatted please check.

Comment: Looks like `context` is null

Comment: How to solve this.

Comment: I think newPhoneState is null you need to make addition check before check if it has value or not

Comment: Toast has shown.So, the Context is NOT NULL.

Comment: please print the Exception and line number.

Comment: How context can be null when audio working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

**Check call state and incoming number on `onReceive()`. And then use `disconnectPhoneItelephony(Context context)` to abort incoming call** -

```
 public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {      
                 if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE") || intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Not phone state", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //return;

                            // Else, try to do some action
                        } else {
                            if (number == null) { //get the incomming call number 
                                number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
             disconnectPhoneItelephony(context); // this is method whick blocks incoming call, this method is provided on the down 
                            }
            }
            }
          }





    // Method to disconnect phone automatically and programmatically
            // Keep this method as it is
            @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
            private void disconnectPhoneItelephony(Context context) {
                try {

                    String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
                    String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
                    String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
                    Class<?> telephonyClass;
                    Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
                    Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
                    Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
                    Method telephonyEndCall;
                    Object telephonyObject;
                    Object serviceManagerObject;
                    telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
                    telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
                    serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
                    serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
                    Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
                            serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
                    Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
                    Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
                    tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
                    serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
                    IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
                    Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
                    telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
                    telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
                    telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("unable", "msg cant disconect call....");

                }


            } 



        }
```

**Here is interface** `ITelephony.java` -

```
interface ITelephony {

    boolean endCall();

}
```

**And dont forget to add permissions and intent filter on your `BroadcastReceiver` class on  your `manifest.xml` file -**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

     <receiver
                android:name=".OutgoingReceiver"
                android:enabled="true">
                <intent-filter android:priority="9999">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"/>

                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

Comment: Sorry java.lang.reflect.InvocatioTarget exception thrown now.

Comment: First try to block all calls. I mean try without accessing DBHelper. Check if blocking is working for all calls or not. I developed a Blacklist app and its working fine on all devices and versions. I just copy/paste this code from my application. So it should work .

Comment: Ohh. One more edition i forgot to change the receiver class on manifest. The Receiver should be your class "OutgoingReceiver". I am making one more edition on my answer.

Comment: Why are you checking the number null before initializing it

Comment: Nothing special, just for security. BTW I modified my answer, you can apply it step by step. It should work.